# Obtenção de valores numéricos de gráficos matemáticos com python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

Supondo que se tenha um arquivo de dados que permita plotar um gráfico 2d (reta, parábola, uma cônica), é possível, partindo da imagem do gráfico extrair os valores numéricos que o geraram?Há algum package, ou técnica  em python que permita isso?

Obs: Sei que é  possivel extrair texto utilizando o tesseract, mas n consegui solucionar a questão acima.

Comment: Eu utilizei o [Engauge Digitizer](https://markummitchell.github.io/engauge-digitizer/) em gráficos de retas que precisei da equação... Pode ajudar em alguns casos.

Answer (score 2):

Não, isso não é uma coisa trivial de se fazer - e não conheço nenhum pacote que possa fazer isso automaticamente.

Dada uma imagem de gráfico específico, é possível fazer isso, claro, tomando-se algumas medidas "artesanais" do gráfico - isso é, posição dos eixos, escalas, etc... e usar programação apenas para saber a posição do gráfico em cada ponto, e usar uma regra de três, possivelmente com propagação de erros, para ter os valroes do gráfico.

A partir daí, métodos comuns de análise numérica, usando scipy, ou mesmo fazendo na mão podem achar os parâmetros do gráfico.

Se os gráficos forem todos no mesmo estilo, é possível generalizar um approach desses o suficiente para automatizar a tarefa.  Se forem gráficos distintos, então um cuidado extra na parte "artesanal", fatorar código para aceitar as medidas tomadas manualmetne como parâmetros, e eventualmente extraí-las automaticamente  a partir da imagem, e aí sim, uso de técnica de  machinne learning para escolher dentre vários modelos de gráfico (depois de saber fazer "manualmente" cada modelo) pode automatizar a coisa de forma mais genérica.

Agora perceba que se você tem os dados numéricos em si, e quer chegar nos parâmetros matemáticos que gerariam um gráfico com aqueles dados numéricos, isso é um campo bem trilhado da física/matemática conhecido como regressão numérica, e algo usado frequentemente em pesquisas - porém não tem nada a ver com a extração de dados a partir de imagens arbitrárias: as fórmulas bem consolidadas há várias e várias décadas precisam dos dados numéricos.

**Em suma:** pacote pronto não tem. É possível. Mas dá trabalho, e trabalho de verdade - então depende da sua necessidade e disponibilidade de recursos se vai atrás disso ou não - e mesmo assim, talvez valha a pena considerar outras formas de fazer isso. Se forem poucas dezenas de gráficos, certamente vale a pena um approach quase que 100% manual (mesmoq ue se use algum programa no computador para facilitar a tomada de medidas - mas poderia ser um programa de desenho) + técnicas matemáticas. Porém, se você tiver *os números* e quiser os parâmetros do gráfico, é um trabalho completamente diferente e factível